# База областей и городов РФ

Tags: sql, база-данных

В БД нужно заполнить таблицы с городами и областями РФ. Где нибудь есть во ВМЕНЯЕМОМ виде эти актуальные данные ?

Comment: в ФИАСе должно быть.

Comment: А чем КЛАДР не устраивает?

Comment: Начал смотреть фиас, пока не понял откуда именно там это можно взять.В архиве который у них опубликован  в  большинстве файлов либо одни гуиды и коды либо типы зданий и документов.  Таблицы с городами и областями не нашел.

Comment: Я точно знаю что есть база стран, городов всего мира. Можешь её скачать, и по ID страны скопировать только РФ, не думаю что она очень часто меняется:)